# Importing Page Titles and Meta Description for selected pages in AEM without having to import pages

Tags: aem

For a client using AEM (according to HTTP Header, Communique 4.2.2, but I presume it is a higher version) we have 600 pages worth of updates to make to SEO items like page title and meta description. There are 8000 pages in total on the website.

Does the [bulk import feature](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/bulk-editor.html#ImportingContent) require me to re-import **all** content? I.e. download an export of all pages, change values of specific fields, upload all content?

If so, is there then another option to only update specifically the pages I want to change, using the path as identifier?

Trying to avoid plain unnecessary copy and paste :)

Note, I do **not** have direct access to AEM myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think editing a website without access to the website management tool defeats the purpose of CMS. All page edits should follow workflow of edit-->review-->Approval-->Publish. You ll need the credentials to logon to server to edit pages. Options available to bulk edit page properties:

Option 1: AEM OTB [Bulk Editor](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/bulk-editing.html). Provided you have AEM console access.

Option 2: [ACS Tools](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/csv-resource-type-updater/index.html) . This tool is written to update only 2 properties. It can be extended to update more properties. You can directly hit the [updateservlet](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-tools/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/tools/csv_resource_type_updater/impl/CsvResourceTypeUpdateServlet.java) custom implementation. No console access required. But this approach requires development of the custom servlet + AEM deployment.

Option 3: Run series of curl commands. For example

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST --data test=sample  http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/jcr:content
```

This updates property 'test' with value 'sample' on page /content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.html. Likewise you can prepare 600 curl commands. No development or console access required. You ll need AEM login credentials (admin:admin) from your OPS team.

Option 4: Using [SlingPostServlet](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html). This again requires development and deployment on AEM.

Comment: Option 1 would require to update all content? Can OTB Bulk Editor update only specific properties on selected pages like curl can?

Comment: No you can run query; fetch desired number of pages; export into spreadsheet; make corrections and import back the spreadsheet. You can refer here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/bulk-editor.html#ImportingContent

Comment: And that would leave other pages untouched, correct? Possible to then delete columns (properties) that you do *not* wish to import?

Comment: Reimport will wipe out previous content of the nodes. So need to careful to retain the exported and edit only the required fields.